# Как получить полностью английскую версию редактора

Tags: c++, netbeans

Всем привет!

Совсем недавно начал осваивать C++ и Netbeans IDE 8.2.

Используемая OS: Ubuntu 16.02.

Установщик, скачанный с официального сайта не дал возможности выбрать язык, поэтому пришлось поменять его после установки ([инструкция](http://orlov.io/ru/articles/netbeans-kak-ystanovit-angliiskii-yazik-interfeisa)).
Интерфейс стал полностью на английском, а логи (ошибки, системные сообщения и т.п.) остались на русском.

Кто-нибудь знает как получить полностью английскую версию программы?

Comment: Вот это должно помочь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869309/selecting-message-language-in-gcc-and-g/8718940

Answer (score 1):

В файле `~/.pam_environment` поменял `LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8` на `LANG=en_GB.UTF-8`.

Проблема была решена, но есть побочные эффекты —  некоторые программы и сервисы ОС начали отображаться на английском